# Writing cssselector expression for webDriver using attribute matching

Tags: java, css, selenium, css-selectors

I am a newbie to css, html, etc and thus cssselectors. I have been messing around with selenium webdriver and am trying to .click() the following button:

```
<button title="" class="btn addWidgButt bt-block" href="" role="button" type="button"     context="UNIQUE_THING">
<span class="btn-text">UNIQUE THING</span></button>
```

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors shouldn't the following selector work? (Rule is E[foo="bar"] for element E

```
By.cssSelector("button title[context=UNIQUE_THING]")
By.cssSelector("btn.addWidgButt.bt-block[context=UNIQUE_THING]")
By.cssSelector("span[btn-text=UNIQUE THING]")
```

I think the last one is my best bet, as span is an element and btn-text is an attribute value. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: One thing you can do to test your CSS selectors: Open the web page in Chrome.  Hit F12 for dev tools.  Ctrl+F for find.  Paste your selector in the search box.  It will show you the number of matches.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that all of your selectors in [] are missing single quotes.

```
By.cssSelector("button[context='UNIQUE_THING']")
By.cssSelector(".btn.addWidgButt.bt-block[context='UNIQUE_THING']")
By.cssSelector("span.btn-text")
```

Your second selector is missing the leading .

Your last selector will not work, as you cannot match text with CSS Selectors.  You can match a class with ., or id with #.

For more information, this is an excellent reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp