# How can I select a link text using a css selector?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have a tabel with more rows and I need to look for specific "selecttext1".
-class myclass is not enough, because it is used for every row
-href="#/test/id_var1 it's changing every time and I don't know its value

```
<td class="myclass">
<a class="ng-binding" href="#/test/id_var1">selectthistext1</a>
</td>

<td class="myclass">
<a class="ng-binding" href="#/test/id_var2">selectthistext2</a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use linktext or xpath as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='selectthistext1']"));
//OR
driver.findElement(By.linkText("selectthistext1"));
```

You may also look at the answer: [Need to find element in selenium by css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288333/need-to-find-element-in-selenium-by-css) and  [Writing cssselector expression for webDriver using attribute matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441098/writing-cssselector-expression-for-webdriver-using-attribute-matching)

Comment: Thank you.Meanwhile I also find: find(By.linkText(var)).containsText(var);

Answer (score -1):

Use the Following CSS Selectors

css=.ng-binding[href*='id_var1'] -- CSS Selector for Link Text selectthistext1

css=.ng-binding[href*='id_var2'] -- CSS Selector for Link Text selectthistext2

Please Let me know is the above CCS  Selectors are working or Not.

Answer (score -1):

You can locate the button with any of the following CSS selector approach

**By Class**

Syntax: tag.Classname

```
By.cssSelector("button.btn addWidgButt bt-block");
```

**By Attribute and Value**

Syntax:  [attribute='value']

```
By.cssSelector("button[context='UNIQUE_THING']")
```